# How to set the python logging class using dictConfig

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm using a dictConfig to setup logging, for example like this:

```
LOGGING_CONF: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any] = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "default",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "my_app": {
            "class": "my_app.logging.MyLogger",  <- Its about this line
            # "()": "my_app.logging.MyLogger",   <- also tried this without success
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "uvicorn": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
}

def init_logging() -> None:
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONF)
```

My question is around the `my_app` logger which I want to use a custom logging class, which does certain things based on additional parameters (enrich with database model references for example).

This configuration above doesn't raise any errors, but also the custom logging class is not used. Is there a way to configure a custom logging class using `dictConfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `logging.config` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects):

> The schema supports user-defined objects for handlers, filters and formatters. (Loggers do not need to have different types for different instances, so **there is no support in this configuration schema for user-defined logger classes**.)

So no, you can't do this with `logging.config.dictConfig`. As far as I can tell, the only way to set a logger class is with [`logging.setLoggerClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass), which sets the class used for all new loggers.

Comment: And here I was thinking that I read the entire thing. Thanks!